# Using Twilio for mobile-app to mobile-app voice calling

Tags: twilio

We have an iPhone app and would like to provide the ability for our users to voice call each other without needing landlines, telephone numbers or use their calling minutes. What is needed with Twilio to do mobile-app to mobile-app voice calls?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at this webpage - https://www.twilio.com/client/mobile

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd start by checking out or [Twilio Client for iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client) quickstart.  The short version is you'll need to set up some kind of back end service that can generate tokens and TwiML instructions, then in your iOS app use our iOS SDK to connect to Twilio and make or receive calls.

Hope that helps.